# javascript return with jQuery.get() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to make a link work if a condition is true for which I am sending a `jQuery.get()`  and checking if the link should jump to the next page or not.

I am using the following code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    function checkDoubleSubmit() {
        jq(function() {
            jq.get("/checkDoubleSubmit",
                    function(data) {
                        if(data == null) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("double submit is not allowed");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
            );
        });
    }
</script>


<a href="<c:url value="/submit" />" onclick="return checkDoubleSubmit();">check double submit</a>
```

Even if `data` is not `null` the page is jumping to the next page.
Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    function checkDoubleSubmit(obj) {
        var checkDoubleSubmitResult;
        jq.ajax({
            url:        "/checkDoubleSubmit",
            success:    function(data) {
                                if(data == null) {
                                    checkDoubleSubmitResult = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("double submit is not allowed");
                                    checkDoubleSubmitResult = false;
                                }
                            },
            async:      false,
            dataType:   "json"
        });
        return checkDoubleSubmitResult;
    }
</script>
<a href="<c:url value="/submit" />" onclick="return checkDoubleSubmit(this);">check double submit</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `ajax` `call` is `asynchronous`. it wont wait for ajax response. for that either include `async = fasle` in ajax call. or change the `preventDefault`.

or change the code as below

```
<a href="#" id="mylink" for="<c:url value="/submit" />" onclick="checkDoubleSubmit();">check double submit</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    function checkDoubleSubmit() {
        jq(function() {
            jq.get("/checkDoubleSubmit",
                    function(data) {
                        if(data == null) {
                            window.location = jq("a#mylink").attr("for");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("double submit is not allowed");
                        }
                    }
            );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For some reasons it doesn't work even with the code above. If the `checkDoubleSubmit(obj)` ends even before I get the data then why should it work? What am I missing here? Also, would `href` not return the same value as `link`? I can't even find a link attribute associated with `<a>`.

Comment: It is still forwarding to the next page :(. the value of data is coming out to be `[object XMLDocument]` but what I am sending back from the server is a json of `Long` java data type. It seems as if the `if(data == null)` is not working :(.

Comment: Finally, I've got this working :). I've pasted the code as an answer. Many thanks to you, ziesemer and bububaba.

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually returning any true/false value from your `checkDoubleSubmit` function.  Your `return` statements are only returning to the anonymous function being used by `jq.get`.

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    function checkDoubleSubmit() {
        var doubleCheckResult;
        jq(function() {
            jq.get("/checkDoubleSubmit",
                    function(data) {
                        if(data == null) {
                            doubleCheckResult = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("double submit is not allowed");
                            doubleCheckResult = false;
                        }
                    }
            );
        });
        return doubleCheckResult;
    }
</script>
```

However, this will only get you started.  See dku's answer for why, and then see [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re) for details on how to implement it.

Comment: This should have been the approach for returning something out of `checkDoubleSubmit()` but how come it doesn't work? I am assuming that `var doubleCheckResult` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`checkDoubleSubmit()` does not return a value, regardless of what you get with `get()`. The execution of `checkDoubleSubmit()` ends before you get AJAX data through `get()` as it's an asynchronous call. You won't get success with handling it this way.

One way to do that would be returning false ALWAYS from `checkDoubleSubmit()`, and then, in the callback function from `get()`, if the data is OK and you want the submit to go through, submit the form by JavaScript again, this time without any checks so that it submits right away.